# TypeError evaluating polynomial

Tags: python, list

Trying to evaluate a function using Horner's rules. Came upon a problem though; I keep receiving "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable". Can anyone quickly help me find a solution to this problem?
Here is my code:

```
def evaluatePoly(poly, x_):
    polyTotal = 0
    for nn in len(poly):
        polyTotal *= x_ + poly[nn]
    return float(polyTotal)
```

poly is coming into the function as a list. I figure that's my problem, but idk how to fix my code to accommodate that.

Comment: `len(poly)` is an integer (the number of items in your `poly` list). You can't iterate on an integer. You might, however, want take a look to what `range` does http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Comment: Actually you don't need to do indexing at all.  Just do `for poly_nn in poly`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with `poly`. You are trying to iterate `nn` over `len(poly)` instead of `range(len(poly))`. However, you're better off using a `foreach` loop anyway which would make your code look like this

```
def evaluatePoly(poly, x_):
  polyTotal = 1
  for i in poly:
    polyTotal *= x_ + i
  return float(polyTotal)
```

`polyTotal` also must be initialized to `1` because `0` times anything is `0`.

Comment: 0 * NaN is not 0. <|:^)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, I don't really think that anyone is going for `NaN * 0`. 0 * Infinity is also not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to iterate over the length of poly, rather than poly itself. Change your code to:

```
def evaluatePoly(poly, x_):
    polyTotal = 1
    for nn in poly:
        polyTotal *= x_ + nn
    return float(polyTotal)
```

Alternatively, if you really want to go by index, you could do:

```
def evaluatePoly(poly, x_):
    polyTotal = 1
    for nn in range(len(poly)):
        polyTotal *= x_ + poly[nn]
    return float(polyTotal)
```

You also want to have polyTotal initialized to something other than 0, likely 1, or else you'll just get 0 every time